# Package ‘GeneR’ is not available

Tags: r, bioconductor, genetics

I'm trying to install GeneR library (http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/GeneR.html):
I'm using win7 and the newest R 2.14.2.

Error during installation:

```
> source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R")
trying URL 'http://www.bioconductor.org/packages/2.9/bioc/bin/windows/contrib/2.14/BiocInstaller_1.2.1.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 32947 bytes (32 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 32 Kb

package ‘BiocInstaller’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded packages are in
        C:\Users\Bluev\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQJYYaS\downloaded_packages
BiocInstaller version 1.2.1, ?biocLite for help
> biocLite("GeneR")
BioC_mirror: 'http://www.bioconductor.org'
Using R version 2.14, BiocInstaller version 1.2.1.
Installing package(s) 'GeneR'
Old packages: 'lattice', 'Matrix', 'rpart'
Update all/some/none? [a/s/n]: a
trying URL 'http://cran.fhcrc.org/bin/windows/contrib/2.14/lattice_0.20-6.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 704272 bytes (687 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 687 Kb

trying URL 'http://cran.fhcrc.org/bin/windows/contrib/2.14/Matrix_1.0-5.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 3278758 bytes (3.1 Mb)
opened URL
downloaded 3.1 Mb

trying URL 'http://cran.fhcrc.org/bin/windows/contrib/2.14/rpart_3.1-52.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 200827 bytes (196 Kb)
opened URL
downloaded 196 Kb

package ‘lattice’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘Matrix’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package ‘rpart’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded packages are in
        C:\Users\Bluev\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQJYYaS\downloaded_packages
Warning message:
In getDependencies(pkgs, dependencies, available, lib) :
  package ‘GeneR’ is not available (for R version 2.14.2)
```

How to install this library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you equipped to install from source? The Bioconctor page for GeneR does not indicate a Windows binary to be available. The Rtools directory is in any CRAN below the  /bin/windows/ node. For example: http://probability.ca/cran/bin/windows/Rtools/

Comment: Thanks for response. I will try to install it from source. And what is interesting is that I was able to install this library under Linux. So it looks like this is only a windows version problem.

Comment: That's correct (but not very interesting). Most Linux packages are installed from source, whereas most Windows are installed from a binary version. If you have Linux experience you will probably have a big "leg up" on the majority of Windows users.